# C# XAML combo box displaying partial information

Tags: c#, xaml

I have an application in XAML that has a combo box which displays the information of SSL Certificates in it. I have a kind of a UI thing here where the full information is not displayed. The information is only displayed up until the length of the combo box. I cannot just increase the length of the combo box because there's limited space to work with and not all combo boxes can be expanded because it would really mess up the look of the app. I was wondering, is there a way to display the full information in the combo box when it is dropped down. Here's how it looks.

[How the combo box looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NawMu.png)

[How it looks when you click the dropdown. Here I select a certificate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlSD5.png)

[Combox box after you've selected a certificate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brbzg.png)

In the third picture, you can see that the selected certificate is only showing partial data, equivalent to the size of the original combo box in the 1st picture. Is there a way I can fix this and make it show the full data?

The XAML code for the combo box is pasted below:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackCertificateSelection" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,25,25,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,5,0">
        <ComboBox materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="10" materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="White" materialDesign:ValidationAssist.Background="White" Foreground="#FF565656" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Certificate Thumbprint" Width="260" x:Name="comboxSelectedCertificate" SelectionChanged="comboboxSelectedCertificate_SelectionChanged" Height="40">
            <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                <Binding Path="SelectedCertificate" Mode="TwoWay" Source="{StaticResource Certs}">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:ComboBoxValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                 </Binding>
             </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a set `Width` for your `ComboBox`
either remove it or set it to be the length of the longest certificate (if you know that in advance)

Comment: I tried doing that but that didn't change anything. When I expand the combo box after selecting a certificate, the selected one's text remains there like in picture 3.

Comment: maybe the ComboBox style `MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox` has something that overrides it?